# What is the easiest way to establish communication between two Dart VMs?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

What is the recommended way to establish communication between two Dart VMs? Isolates, as recommended [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/eCklr5rOMoU)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the question!

If the two Dart VMs are running on the server, I would consider using TCP sockets.

You can start a [ServerSocket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/ServerSocket.html) to listen for incoming requests. You can use a [Socket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/Socket.html) to connect to the other server.

Isolates haven't been extended to cross-VM communication yet. That may happen in the future, but it's not on our near-term roadmap.

Comment: A simple example would go a long way for this answer.